# What is the exact scope of the jsp scriptlet local variables?

Tags: jsp, variables, scope

I would like to know what's excatly the variable scope of the scriptlet local variables. For example:

```
<% String strong = "Indeed it is strong"; %>
```

I have noticed that I can call it from a JSP expression like this

```
<%= strong %>
```

So I guess we can talk about "page scope". Is there any documentation explaining the scopes of JSP variables? I have not found it yet. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

A JSP is a servlet.

A variable declared like this ends up in its service method, e.g., local to the service method.

A variable defined with a "bang", e.g., `<%! String s = "hi"; %>` is at the servlet's class level.

Answer (score 1):

When we use `<% %>` for a variable, we define a local variable, which is valid only on the current web page. If someone refreshes the web page, this variable will be defined again, thus its value will return back to the original.

When we use `<%! %>` for variable, we define a global variable, which is generic through pages. It's just defined once. For example, we define a global which would increase itself each time web page was refreshed, so if we refresh the web page, the variable would increase instead of returning back to the original value.

Comment: This is largely correct, but servlet instances *can* be re-instantiated under container control under some circumstances.